# Getting specific attribute from JSON for Typeahead

Tags: json, typeahead.js

All of the JSON items are formatted like this and saved to /database.json:

```
"[{\"ndb_no\":01001,\"shrt_desc\":\"BUTTER,WITH SALT\",\"water_(g)\":15.87,\"energ_kcal\":717},\n
{\"ndb_no\":01002,\"shrt_desc\":\"BUTTER,WHIPPED,WITH SALT\",\"water_(g)\":15.87,\"energ_kcal\":717}]"
```

I want to create a typeahead with all the `shrt_desc` attributes, all of the tutorials/examples I have found have been very basic and didn't involve files with more than one attribute.

This is what I put together but I didn't work:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <input class="typeahead" type="text">
</div>

<script>

var description = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('shrt_desc'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  limit: 10,
  prefetch: {

    url: '/database.json',

  }
});




$('#prefetch .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'countries',
  displayKey: 'shrt_desc',
  source: countries.ttAdapter()
});

</script>
```

Let me know if I should add some more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has various errors. Look at the comments below:

```
var description = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('shrt_desc'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  limit: 10,
  prefetch: {

    url: '/database.json',

  }
});

description.initialize() /****** THIS WAS MISSING ******/


$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {    /***** gotta match an existing input ***/
  name: 'countries',
  displayKey: 'shrt_desc',
  source: description.ttAdapter() /***** WAS countries.ttAdapter(), countries does not exist ****/
});

</script>
```

**but**, since this can be easily seen in the typeahead example from which you based your code, I assume what really got you is the invalid JSON:

> JSON integer MUST NOT start with a zero (0)

your ndb_no fields are starting with zero. This is breaking bloodhound/typeahead, causing them to fail silently. Just quote them, and apply the fixes I mentioned and you should be good to go.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get a response. What exactly does `name:` do because I got that from another source and forgot to change it? Could you maybe give a source on the 0 thing? It's hard to believe (I'm not doubting, would just like proof).Thank you for the response

Comment: http://www.json.org/, http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonParser.Feature.html#ALLOW_NUMERIC_LEADING_ZEROS, or just google "JSON leading zeros" and you'll see you're not the only one to have this problem. "name" is just used to form the class name of the element, see https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md

Comment: I do appreciate the help but the typeahead is still not working even without leading zeros.